# Pasting into Android Studio brings in inline imports, rather than importing properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I have one project open and two classes are open side by side. I copy this from the left file:

```
onView(allOf(
    withId(viewId), withText(containsString(text)), withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

And paste into the right file, which then turns into:

```
onView(
    CoreMatchers.allOf(
        ViewMatchers.withId(viewId),
        ViewMatchers.withText(CoreMatchers.containsString(text)),
        ViewMatchers.withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)
    )
)
    .check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
```

Then I have to manually delete all the prefix parts like "CoreMatchers" and "ViewMatchers" and then import them properly, all individually and tedious.

How can I stop Android Studio from adding them in?